# Elements out of body

Tags: html, css

i'm new in css and i started to code an extension, but i have a problem :
the div elements in the extension display out of it.
I putted them in a normal html page and the problem is still there.
I put the code of the page down there.
The only thing i want to do is restrict the divs inside the body but i don't find how to.
Thanks for the help you can bring

```css
div.loading_div{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -110px 0 0 -50px;
}
img.loading_gif{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

html{
}

body{
    height: 480px;
    width: 260px;
    background-color: #181818
}

label:hover{
    cursor: text;
}

div.streamer_div{
    position: relative;
    width:fit-content;
    height:fit-content;
}

label.loading_label{
    font-family: "Futura";
    display: block;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #70726e;
}

img.streamer_img{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

img.game_picture{
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ;
    transition: all .5s ;
}

img.user_pp{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<html><head><link rel="shortcut icon" href="../icons/tf-48.png" type="image/x-icon">
  
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/new.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/new.css">
  </head>
 <body><div class="top_div" id="top_div1"><div class="user_pp_div" id="user_pp_div1"><a href="https://twitch.tv/ponce" class="user_link" id="link_ponce" target="_blank"><img src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/125bbc49-45d1-432c-92b3-f5aef1e7ab21-profile_image-300x300.png" class="user_pp" id="pp_ponce"></a></div><div class="user_stats_div" id="user_stats_div1"><label class="username_label" id="label_ponce">Ponce</label><btn class="asker_btn" id="asker_btn2">Change account</btn></div></div><div class="streamer_div" id="streamer_chowh1"><a class="streamer_link" id="link_chowh1" href="https://twitch.tv/chowh1" target="_blank" title="chowh1 - #1  SUPERSTAR CHOWH1  !youtube 200.000 SUR YOUTUBE :) - Call of Duty: Warzone"><img class="streamer_img" id="img_chowh1" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/1b41d9b0-f1d0-4467-9968-acd5baa00722-profile_image-300x300.png"><img class="game_picture" id="picture_game_512710" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/512710-285x380.jpg"></a></div><div class="streamer_div" id="streamer_shaunz"><a class="streamer_link" id="link_shaunz" href="https://twitch.tv/shaunz" target="_blank" title="Shaunz - SHAUNZ - SET 6  RANKED TFT  - Teamfight Tactics"><img class="streamer_img" id="img_shaunz" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/7b106348-fa76-466c-9a32-4568b7cadaf4-profile_image-300x300.png"><img class="game_picture" id="picture_game_513143" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/513143-285x380.jpg"></a></div><div class="streamer_div" id="streamer_sardoche"><a class="streamer_link" id="link_sardoche" href="https://twitch.tv/sardoche" target="_blank" title="Sardoche - SARDOCHE - ZELDA - TUER GANON - The Legend of Zelda: Breath of the Wild"><img class="streamer_img" id="img_sardoche" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/2b1b9e13-5b9f-41ee-b375-54d3c6491bb2-profile_image-300x300.png"><img class="game_picture" id="picture_game_110758" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/110758-285x380.jpg" style="width: 40px; height: 50px;"></a></div><div class="streamer_div" id="streamer_alexclick"><a class="streamer_link" id="link_alexclick" href="https://twitch.tv/alexclick" target="_blank" title="Alexclick - Miguel - S4E7 |21 Jump Click| !21 !21live !shop - Grand Theft Auto V"><img class="streamer_img" id="img_alexclick" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/c9ab63d5f7e93091-profile_image-300x300.png"><img class="game_picture" id="picture_game_32982" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/32982-285x380.jpg"></a></div><div class="streamer_div" id="streamer_solary"><a class="streamer_link" id="link_solary" href="https://twitch.tv/solary" target="_blank" title="Solary - WAKZ CEO : KALISTA BROKEN ? FRIST STRIKE OP ? JE VOUS DIS TOUT ET JE FAIS TAIRE LES RUMEURS, DEVENEZ UN MAVERICK ENTREPRENEUR  - League of Legends"><img class="streamer_img" id="img_solary" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/3b6094ef-a538-42c9-ad59-25a0fe719ee2-profile_image-300x300.png"><img class="game_picture" id="picture_game_21779" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/21779-285x380.jpg"></a></div><div class="streamer_div" id="streamer_lestream"><a class="streamer_link" id="link_lestream" href="https://twitch.tv/lestream" target="_blank" title="lestream - LE LUNCHPLAY EX | lestream - Just Chatting"><img class="streamer_img" id="img_lestream" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/c0f93540-556a-44a6-9c74-ea0fafea8115-profile_image-300x300.png"><img class="game_picture" id="picture_game_509658" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/509658-285x380.jpg" style="width: 40px; height: 50px;"></a></div><div class="streamer_div" id="streamer_jeeltv"><a class="streamer_link" id="link_jeeltv" href="https://twitch.tv/jeeltv" target="_blank" title="JeelTV - 9h - ? : SORTEZ LES POKEBALL ! Go Pokemon Perle Scintillante !AlienWare - 19/11/2021 - Pokémon Brilliant Diamond/Shining Pearl"><img class="streamer_img" id="img_jeeltv" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/3845db6c-1ea5-47de-906a-e41b60fa31db-profile_image-300x300.png"><img class="game_picture" id="picture_game_1584745140" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/1584745140-285x380.jpg" style="width: 40px; height: 50px;"></a></div><div class="streamer_div" id="streamer_skyrroztv"><a class="streamer_link" id="link_skyrroztv" href="https://twitch.tv/skyrroztv" target="_blank" title="SkyrrozTV - NOUVEL ALERT SUB ☢️ !Alienware ☢️ code SKYRROZ dans la Boutique - Call of Duty: Warzone"><img class="streamer_img" id="img_skyrroztv" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/849d425c-ad56-4376-a782-bb864b205831-profile_image-300x300.png"><img class="game_picture" id="picture_game_512710" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/512710-285x380.jpg"></a></div><div class="streamer_div" id="streamer_lebouseuh"><a class="streamer_link" id="link_lebouseuh" href="https://twitch.tv/lebouseuh" target="_blank" title="LeBouseuh - BOUZI -> Début d'aventure ! //Pokemon Perle #1 - Pokémon Brilliant Diamond/Shining Pearl"><img class="streamer_img" id="img_lebouseuh" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/9a6e58e5-2da6-47e4-a4ce-eb91a0d1572d-profile_image-300x300.png"><img class="game_picture" id="picture_game_1584745140" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/1584745140-285x380.jpg"></a></div><div class="streamer_div" id="streamer_ultia"><a class="streamer_link" id="link_ultia" href="https://twitch.tv/ultia" target="_blank" title="Ultia - ULTIA -  POKEMON DIAMANT A POAAAAL !jeu !youtube - Just Chatting"><img class="streamer_img" id="img_ultia" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/5e6a5413-b748-4880-8a60-2639cb55fe74-profile_image-300x300.png"><img class="game_picture" id="picture_game_509658" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/509658-285x380.jpg"></a></div><div class="streamer_div" id="streamer_damdamlive"><a class="streamer_link" id="link_damdamlive" href="https://twitch.tv/damdamlive" target="_blank" title="DamDamLive - [LEGO] Construction de la LAMBORGHINI SIAN, plus grosse automobile Lego Technic // !lego !pause - Just Chatting"><img class="streamer_img" id="img_damdamlive" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/c5db4a62-9d05-4184-84b4-f64e3e391441-profile_image-300x300.png"><img class="game_picture" id="picture_game_509658" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/509658-285x380.jpg"></a></div><div class="streamer_div" id="streamer_solaryhs"><a class="streamer_link" id="link_solaryhs" href="https://twitch.tv/solaryhs" target="_blank" title="SolaryHS - [FR] Diz : échauffement avant le MT - Hearthstone"><img class="streamer_img" id="img_solaryhs" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/6db903c8-5eea-4815-b36e-4acb0e6dbf90-profile_image-300x300.jpeg"><img class="game_picture" id="picture_game_138585" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/138585-285x380.jpg"></a></div><div class="streamer_div" id="streamer_rhobalas_lol"><a class="streamer_link" id="link_rhobalas_lol" href="https://twitch.tv/rhobalas_lol" target="_blank" title="rhobalas_lol - FNATIC RHOBALAS - TEST PRESAISON PUIS PUSH LEGENDE SUR POKEMON GO !rhinoshield !giveaway - League of Legends"><img class="streamer_img" id="img_rhobalas_lol" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/ab7be94b-dd10-43ad-9a81-ef1b021fd2e1-profile_image-300x300.png"><img class="game_picture" id="picture_game_21779" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/21779-285x380.jpg" style="width: 40px; height: 50px;"></a></div><div class="streamer_div" id="streamer_teuf"><a class="streamer_link" id="link_teuf" href="https://twitch.tv/teuf" target="_blank" title="Teuf - Start 5000€⚡️ !giveaway !social !stake  - Slots"><img class="streamer_img" id="img_teuf" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/3ebda7f8-ab67-4197-841a-9b8d58595c1d-profile_image-300x300.png"><img class="game_picture" id="picture_game_498566" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/498566-285x380.jpg"></a></div><div class="streamer_div" id="streamer_gobgg"><a class="streamer_link" id="link_gobgg" href="https://twitch.tv/gobgg" target="_blank" title="GoBGG - OUAIS DU TFT ON VA PASSER D1 UN JOUR !ugg !corsair !giveaway - Teamfight Tactics"><img class="streamer_img" id="img_gobgg" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/2935acd6-494d-4a15-b340-adbe368c1aca-profile_image-300x300.png"><img class="game_picture" id="picture_game_513143" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/513143-285x380.jpg"></a></div><div class="streamer_div" id="streamer_gius"><a class="streamer_link" id="link_gius" href="https://twitch.tv/gius" target="_blank" title="Gius - Je vous attends les petits nouveaux ! !airup !video !Boutique - Battlefield 2042"><img class="streamer_img" id="img_gius" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/b6bdd5ad-c523-4610-9292-a78389434a4f-profile_image-300x300.png"><img class="game_picture" id="picture_game_514974" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/514974-285x380.jpg"></a></div><div class="streamer_div" id="streamer_linca"><a class="streamer_link" id="link_linca" href="https://twitch.tv/linca" target="_blank" title="Linca - LINCA - Marathon 15h Pokémon Perle Scintillante ! (!volvic !fulllife) - Pokémon Brilliant Diamond/Shining Pearl"><img class="streamer_img" id="img_linca" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/b9ee41fa-de30-412b-bd35-88ce0ea8ecd0-profile_image-300x300.png"><img class="game_picture" id="picture_game_1584745140" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/1584745140-285x380.jpg"></a></div><div class="streamer_div" id="streamer_gautoz"><a class="streamer_link" id="link_gautoz" href="https://twitch.tv/gautoz" target="_blank" title="Gautoz -  Le Smash Bros de Warner, Microsoft, Sony et le monde contre Bobby Kotick, It's Friday Then ☕ MATINALE ACTU JV !utip - Just Chatting"><img class="streamer_img" id="img_gautoz" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/425d2294-2f87-425a-9fa0-ded1df581758-profile_image-300x300.png"><img class="game_picture" id="picture_game_509658" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/509658-285x380.jpg"></a></div><div class="streamer_div" id="streamer_zoltan"><a class="streamer_link" id="link_zoltan" href="https://twitch.tv/zoltan" target="_blank" title="Zoltan - On talk &amp; on play à FF14! Bobby Kotick, Acti/Blizzard, situation - Merci la team pour le soutien <3 | !rs  - Just Chatting"><img class="streamer_img" id="img_zoltan" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/1516e9ae-7dad-4d80-9b1a-146c7dce2929-profile_image-300x300.png"><img class="game_picture" id="picture_game_509658" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/509658-285x380.jpg"></a></div><div class="streamer_div" id="streamer_dahmien7"><a class="streamer_link" id="link_dahmien7" href="https://twitch.tv/dahmien7" target="_blank" title="dahmien7 -  Vendredi = Pubg + Musique !dono !levlup !shop - PUBG: BATTLEGROUNDS"><img class="streamer_img" id="img_dahmien7" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/44ca9f61-637b-493a-a5e7-5b0c0524f22d-profile_image-300x300.png"><img class="game_picture" id="picture_game_493057" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/493057-285x380.jpg"></a></div><div class="streamer_div" id="streamer_solaryfortnite"><a class="streamer_link" id="link_solaryfortnite" href="https://twitch.tv/solaryfortnite" target="_blank" title="SolaryFortnite - TIER LIST SAISON HUNTY | ANNONCE FORTNITE A 21H  - Fortnite"><img class="streamer_img" id="img_solaryfortnite" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/41bcfffb-29d4-433e-a13e-6fdf40bebc89-profile_image-300x300.png"><img class="game_picture" id="picture_game_33214" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/33214-285x380.jpg" style="width: 40px; height: 50px;"></a></div><div class="streamer_div" id="streamer_hari_live"><a class="streamer_link" id="link_hari_live" href="https://twitch.tv/hari_live" target="_blank" title="Hari_Live - REMAKES 4G CHALLENGE !challenge !emotes - Pokémon Brilliant Diamond/Shining Pearl"><img class="streamer_img" id="img_hari_live" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/8d506a0c-6d5d-4304-9205-63fc26c03c02-profile_image-300x300.png"><img class="game_picture" id="picture_game_1584745140" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/1584745140-285x380.jpg"></a></div><div class="streamer_div" id="streamer_yann"><a class="streamer_link" id="link_yann" href="https://twitch.tv/yann" target="_blank" title="Yann - YANNL’aventure FORZA HORIZON 5 - Forza Horizon 5"><img class="streamer_img" id="img_yann" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/50ebbd29-73f4-42f4-b4a8-f91480025187-profile_image-300x300.png"><img class="game_picture" id="picture_game_1757732267" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/1757732267-285x380.jpg"></a></div><div class="streamer_div" id="streamer_marexlol"><a class="streamer_link" id="link_marexlol" href="https://twitch.tv/marexlol" target="_blank" title="MarexLoL - MAREX  TEST DE DINGZ S12 RANKED - MAMAA (Double-GM secured) !displate - League of Legends"><img class="streamer_img" id="img_marexlol" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/9cbe18ed-3211-4566-816b-903db5c509fb-profile_image-300x300.png"><img class="game_picture" id="picture_game_21779" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/21779-285x380.jpg"></a></div><div class="streamer_div" id="streamer_awkwards_travel"><a class="streamer_link" id="link_awkwards_travel" href="https://twitch.tv/awkwards_travel" target="_blank" title="Awkwards_Travel - BANGKOK: River Festival!!! - Just Chatting"><img class="streamer_img" id="img_awkwards_travel" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/f94fdd31-4605-4cd7-9ce7-6b588e6579d6-profile_image-300x300.png"><img class="game_picture" id="picture_game_509658" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/509658-285x380.jpg" style="width: 40px; height: 50px;"></a></div><div class="streamer_div" id="streamer_trinity"><a class="streamer_link" id="link_trinity" href="https://twitch.tv/trinity" target="_blank" title="Trinity -  Blabla &amp; lalafel !ff14 | PublicitéParSquareEnix | !social !voyage  - Final Fantasy XIV Online"><img class="streamer_img" id="img_trinity" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/cfbb72a6-c6a0-4808-8736-794c5f759d01-profile_image-300x300.png"><img class="game_picture" id="picture_game_24241" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/24241-285x380.jpg" style="width: 40px; height: 50px;"></a></div><div class="streamer_div" id="streamer_mywtheking"><a class="streamer_link" id="link_mywtheking" href="https://twitch.tv/mywtheking" target="_blank" title="MywTheKing - Myw / Trynda top - League of Legends"><img class="streamer_img" id="img_mywtheking" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/fd865b68-fd86-4c75-8065-fd09c1c7d0b2-profile_image-300x300.png"><img class="game_picture" id="picture_game_21779" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/21779-285x380.jpg"></a></div><div class="streamer_div" id="streamer_mickalow"><a class="streamer_link" id="link_mickalow" href="https://twitch.tv/mickalow" target="_blank" title="Mickalow - Le Voleur de rang est de retour !! - Rocket League"><img class="streamer_img" id="img_mickalow" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/8b183655-aca2-4bb2-b97f-52a92ed8559a-profile_image-300x300.png"><img class="game_picture" id="picture_game_30921" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/30921-285x380.jpg" style="width: 40px; height: 50px;"></a></div><div class="streamer_div" id="streamer_titavion"><a class="streamer_link" id="link_titavion" href="https://twitch.tv/titavion" target="_blank" title="TiTavion - Halloweenathon 6 - Dead Space 3 !Halloweenathon - Dead Space 3"><img class="streamer_img" id="img_titavion" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/bba2eb66-6d9b-4524-8369-8b70f71237cd-profile_image-300x300.png"><img class="game_picture" id="picture_game_65706" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/65706-285x380.jpg" style="width: 40px; height: 50px;"></a></div><div class="streamer_div" id="streamer_armateam"><a class="streamer_link" id="link_armateam" href="https://twitch.tv/armateam" target="_blank" title="armateam - TORLK : STOP TROLL FULL REMONTADA BORDEL - Teamfight Tactics"><img class="streamer_img" id="img_armateam" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/e38c722d-e0d0-414c-9a5c-d8a2c4943d2d-profile_image-300x300.jpg"><img class="game_picture" id="picture_game_513143" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/513143-285x380.jpg"></a></div><div class="streamer_div" id="streamer_cruelladk"><a class="streamer_link" id="link_cruelladk" href="https://twitch.tv/cruelladk" target="_blank" title="Cruelladk - <Method> Pleins d'infos sur la 9.2 - Raid Ally HM viewers à 14h - IRL ce week end !!! !esn - World of Warcraft"><img class="streamer_img" id="img_cruelladk" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/b8d02b21-4f6a-4549-a1d0-0ea229e88022-profile_image-300x300.png"><img class="game_picture" id="picture_game_18122" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/18122-285x380.jpg"></a></div><div class="streamer_div" id="streamer_jussetain"><a class="streamer_link" id="link_jussetain" href="https://twitch.tv/jussetain" target="_blank" title="Jussetain -  Enquête sur le Obra Dinn (no backseat/spoil) - !backseat !spoil !subgoal !prime - Return of the Obra Dinn"><img class="streamer_img" id="img_jussetain" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/57002cf3-d9f6-43b5-a576-31479b869602-profile_image-300x300.png"><img class="game_picture" id="picture_game_460501" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/460501-285x380.jpg"></a></div><div class="streamer_div" id="streamer_hexakil"><a class="streamer_link" id="link_hexakil" href="https://twitch.tv/hexakil" target="_blank" title="Hexakil - HYYYYPE - JOUR 1 de la découverte, objectif charme chroma (pas forcément pour ajd le charme hein) - Pokémon Brilliant Diamond/Shining Pearl"><img class="streamer_img" id="img_hexakil" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/a978d6bab908c3a5-profile_image-300x300.png"><img class="game_picture" id="picture_game_1584745140" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/1584745140-285x380.jpg"></a></div><div class="streamer_div" id="streamer_nagaserya"><a class="streamer_link" id="link_nagaserya" href="https://twitch.tv/nagaserya" target="_blank" title="Nagaserya - !EHSAC [C: 02-PB: 99] Psytrance | !Playtime !Gb !GOG - The Binding of Isaac: Repentance"><img class="streamer_img" id="img_nagaserya" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/7cba3bb7-2411-4331-bdc7-3862ca159be2-profile_image-300x300.png"><img class="game_picture" id="picture_game_491080" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/491080-285x380.jpg"></a></div><div class="streamer_div" id="streamer_kinstaar"><a class="streamer_link" id="link_kinstaar" href="https://twitch.tv/kinstaar" target="_blank" title="kinstaar - Not Partner Elyon☠️❗️elyondiscord - ❗️build - ❗️gear - ❗️elyon - ❗️ytb - ❗️myprotein - ❗️pc - ELYON"><img class="streamer_img" id="img_kinstaar" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/fbbde0a1-b7d1-4583-8a7c-3263d38241ae-profile_image-300x300.png"><img class="game_picture" id="picture_game_500907" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/500907-285x380.jpg"></a></div><div class="streamer_div" id="streamer_adztv"><a class="streamer_link" id="link_adztv" href="https://twitch.tv/adztv" target="_blank" title="AdzTV - STREAM 6H - CHAQUE 25 SUBS = +1H #STONKS - Fortnite"><img class="streamer_img" id="img_adztv" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/ef1579ec-778e-48d1-9410-9f33e952e671-profile_image-300x300.png"><img class="game_picture" id="picture_game_33214" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/33214-285x380.jpg"></a></div><div class="streamer_div" id="streamer_oslo"><a class="streamer_link" id="link_oslo" href="https://twitch.tv/oslo" target="_blank" title="Oslo - LE MEILLEUR SNIPER AU MONDE | !prime - Battlefield 2042"><img class="streamer_img" id="img_oslo" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/a7e1ab25-c2f8-41fb-a890-6746aaab114f-profile_image-300x300.png"><img class="game_picture" id="picture_game_514974" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/514974-285x380.jpg"></a></div><div class="streamer_div" id="streamer_nono_lol"><a class="streamer_link" id="link_nono_lol" href="https://twitch.tv/nono_lol" target="_blank" title="Nono_LoL - ZE SUIS BALADE - Teamfight Tactics"><img class="streamer_img" id="img_nono_lol" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/11bbbde2-f081-4ab2-bc51-2be3fffdb73d-profile_image-300x300.png"><img class="game_picture" id="picture_game_513143" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/513143-285x380.jpg"></a></div><div class="streamer_div" id="streamer_chunklaw"><a class="streamer_link" id="link_chunklaw" href="https://twitch.tv/chunklaw" target="_blank" title="Chunklaw -  [FR/PC] Dernier défis saisonnier et twab discussion❗config ❗hello  - Destiny 2"><img class="streamer_img" id="img_chunklaw" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/125dbc62-68df-4635-8151-14009c372044-profile_image-300x300.png"><img class="game_picture" id="picture_game_497057" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/497057-285x380.jpg"></a></div><div class="streamer_div" id="streamer_aifetv"><a class="streamer_link" id="link_aifetv" href="https://twitch.tv/aifetv" target="_blank" title="AifeTV - On part chasser des Pokémons ? - Just Chatting"><img class="streamer_img" id="img_aifetv" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/45d731dd-6ba5-444d-a3ec-bda20e5babbc-profile_image-300x300.png"><img class="game_picture" id="picture_game_509658" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/509658-285x380.jpg"></a></div><div class="streamer_div" id="streamer_kha_len"><a class="streamer_link" id="link_kha_len" href="https://twitch.tv/kha_len" target="_blank" title="Kha_LeN - Dernier pokemon en 2004 lets go !  LDLC OL #FoxSpirit - Pokémon Brilliant Diamond/Shining Pearl"><img class="streamer_img" id="img_kha_len" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/625e0fbf-652d-4859-86be-7cd73cc8c237-profile_image-300x300.png"><img class="game_picture" id="picture_game_1584745140" src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/1584745140-285x380.jpg"></a></div></body></html>
```

Edit :
For now, i haven't found any solution, it appears like i will have to deal with that... Good luck if you have the same problem !

Comment: What do you mean with "restrict" the divs? Do you want them on a single line or do you want to be able to put a fixed size to them?

Comment: I want to fix their size.

Answer (score 0):

You can put `overflow hidden` or `overflow: auto` on the body depending on if you want to let the user scroll or not.

```
body {
    height: 480px;
    width: 260px;
    background-color: #181818;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: the problem was not on the scralling bar but in the size.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that your images don't exceed a certain size you can use the `max-width` and `max-height` properties as shown in the snippet below.

To look up at some tutorials and more info about it, I suggest you to check [this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_max-width.asp). Also, I strongly suggest to take a look also to [css selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp), in order to learn how to use more effectively css' `id`s and `class`es.

```css
div.loading_div{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -110px 0 0 -50px;
}
img.loading_gif{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

html{
}

body{
    height: 480px;
    width: 260px;
    background-color: #181818
}

label:hover{
    cursor: text;
}

div.streamer_div{
    position: relative;
    width:fit-content;
    height:fit-content;
    max-width: 50px; /* like here */
    max-height: 50px; /* like here */
}

label.loading_label{
    font-family: "Futura";
    display: block;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #70726e;
}

img.streamer_img{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    max-width: 50px; /* like here */
    max-height: 50px; /* like here */
    border-radius: 10px;
}

img.game_picture{
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ;
    transition: all .5s ;
}

img.user_pp{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link
            rel="shortcut icon"
            href="../icons/tf-48.png"
            type="image/x-icon"
        />

        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/new.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/new.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="top_div" id="top_div1">
            <div class="user_pp_div" id="user_pp_div1">
                <a
                    href="https://twitch.tv/ponce"
                    class="user_link"
                    id="link_ponce"
                    target="_blank"
                    ><img
                        src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/125bbc49-45d1-432c-92b3-f5aef1e7ab21-profile_image-300x300.png"
                        class="user_pp"
                        id="pp_ponce"
                /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="user_stats_div" id="user_stats_div1">
                <label class="username_label" id="label_ponce">Ponce</label
                ><btn class="asker_btn" id="asker_btn2">Change account</btn>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="streamer_div" id="streamer_chowh1">
            <a
                class="streamer_link"
                id="link_chowh1"
                href="https://twitch.tv/chowh1"
                target="_blank"
                title="chowh1 - #1  SUPERSTAR CHOWH1  !youtube 200.000 SUR YOUTUBE :) - Call of Duty: Warzone"
                ><img
                    class="streamer_img"
                    id="img_chowh1"
                    src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/1b41d9b0-f1d0-4467-9968-acd5baa00722-profile_image-300x300.png" /><img
                    class="game_picture"
                    id="picture_game_512710"
                    src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/512710-285x380.jpg"
            /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="streamer_div" id="streamer_shaunz">
            <a
                class="streamer_link"
                id="link_shaunz"
                href="https://twitch.tv/shaunz"
                target="_blank"
                title="Shaunz - SHAUNZ - SET 6  RANKED TFT  - Teamfight Tactics"
                ><img
                    class="streamer_img"
                    id="img_shaunz"
                    src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/7b106348-fa76-466c-9a32-4568b7cadaf4-profile_image-300x300.png" /><img
                    class="game_picture"
                    id="picture_game_513143"
                    src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/513143-285x380.jpg"
            /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="streamer_div" id="streamer_sardoche">
            <a
                class="streamer_link"
                id="link_sardoche"
                href="https://twitch.tv/sardoche"
                target="_blank"
                title="Sardoche - SARDOCHE - ZELDA - TUER GANON - The Legend of Zelda: Breath of the Wild"
                ><img
                    class="streamer_img"
                    id="img_sardoche"
                    src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/2b1b9e13-5b9f-41ee-b375-54d3c6491bb2-profile_image-300x300.png" /><img
                    class="game_picture"
                    id="picture_game_110758"
                    src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/110758-285x380.jpg"
                    style="width: 40px; height: 50px"
            /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="streamer_div" id="streamer_alexclick">
            <a
                class="streamer_link"
                id="link_alexclick"
                href="https://twitch.tv/alexclick"
                target="_blank"
                title="Alexclick - Miguel - S4E7 |21 Jump Click| !21 !21live !shop - Grand Theft Auto V"
                ><img
                    class="streamer_img"
                    id="img_alexclick"
                    src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/c9ab63d5f7e93091-profile_image-300x300.png" /><img
                    class="game_picture"
                    id="picture_game_32982"
                    src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/32982-285x380.jpg"
            /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="streamer_div" id="streamer_solary">
            <a
                class="streamer_link"
                id="link_solary"
                href="https://twitch.tv/solary"
                target="_blank"
                title="Solary - WAKZ CEO : KALISTA BROKEN ? FRIST STRIKE OP ? JE VOUS DIS TOUT ET JE FAIS TAIRE LES RUMEURS, DEVENEZ UN MAVERICK ENTREPRENEUR  - League of Legends"
                ><img
                    class="streamer_img"
                    id="img_solary"
                    src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/3b6094ef-a538-42c9-ad59-25a0fe719ee2-profile_image-300x300.png" /><img
                    class="game_picture"
                    id="picture_game_21779"
                    src="https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/21779-285x380.jpg"
            /></a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but here is not the problem. The problem should come from chrome, but the extension's windows do not limit it size to the body one or the html one, and i would like to fix it.

Comment: Well, if you're using css, the same logic should apply